# JQGrid shows multiple Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Non working version

[image]

```
be = "<a href='#'>Select</a >";
be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetEnrollmentByCIP(\"" + (rowId['CIP']) + "\")'>Select</a >";
jQuery("#grdProgramsEnrolled").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { ab: be });
```

This is what `be` is in the last row when loading the grid:

```
<a href='#' onclick='GetEnrollmentByCIP("52.0299")'>Select</a >
```

Why am I getting (2) Select statements from the above code?

This code only produces as single "Select" on a different screen

```
be = "<a href='#'>Student</a >";
be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetStudent(\"" + (rowId['UIC']) + "\")'>Student</a >";
jQuery("#grdStudentGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { ab: be });
```

This is what `be` is in the last row when loading the grid:

```
 <a href='#' onclick='GetStudent("7910132816")'>Student</a >
```

The only difference that I can tell is that the string value being passed contains a decimal point? Does s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you want to call a function depending on the row data that is selected.
Instead of the onclick crammed there, you can use the custom formatter of jqgrid to do the same.

```
function myformatter ( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
var obj = rowObject['CIP']
return '<a href ="#" onclick="GetEnrollmentByCIP(' + obj+ ')">Select</a>';
}
```

For details:: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Comment: Well the above piece of code is much cleaner then my version but alas, no success with trying to pass my values if I have a value of 01.0000 my select event will not initiate. If I have a value of 12.0000 it will initiate.                                                    Doesn't work
<a href ="#" onclick="GetEnrollmentByCIP(01.0000)">Select</a>
Does work
<a href ="#" onclick="GetEnrollmentByCIP(52.0299)">Select</a>

Comment: It seems like there is a bit of a formatting error with the preceding 0 like 01.0000 rather an 1.0000. Maybe formatting of the data will help.